# Can't split text that contain "|" in String

Tags: java, string, split

I'm wondering why I cannot split a text that contain the **|** as a separator in String. The splitting works fine when I use commas or the like..

Here is an SSCE

```
package tests;

public class Tests {        
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text1="one|two|three|four|five";
        String text2="one,two,three,four,five";

        String [] splittedText1 = text1.split("|");
        String [] splittedText2 = text2.split(",");

        for(String elem : splittedText1) System.out.println("text1="+elem);
        for(String elem : splittedText2) System.out.println("text2="+elem);
    }    
}
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work with "|" ??

Comment: If you want to impress your friends, use `Pattern#quote`: `String [] splittedText1 = text1.split(Pattern.quote("|"));`

Comment: @MarounMaroun I  impressed you :D

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ As always

Comment: very impressive :-). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since  `split(String regex)` takes a `regex` and | is a meta character, you need to escape it.

```
String[] splittedText1 = splittedText1.split("\\|");
```

Or you can simply use [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class

> A compiled representation of a regular expression.

```
String[] splittedText1 = splittedText1.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Because the split pattern is actually a regex. You need to escape `|`, since it has a special meaning in the context of a regular expression (it marks an alternative):

```
String [] splittedText1 = text1.split("\\|");
```